# How to use If Else in SSRS expression

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to evaluate a text box value using SSSRS expression.

Currently I am doing something like following:

```
=IIF(Fields!VariableValue.Value =1,"Pass",IIF(Fields!VariableValue.Value = 2,"Fail",IIF(Fields!VariableValue.Value = 3,"Abort",IIF(Fields!VariableValue.Value = 4,"ByPass",IIF(Fields!VariableValue.Value ="#Error","NA",Fields!VariableValue.Value)))))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not perfect, but you can use [SWITCH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) to make it a bit easier to read:

```
=Switch
(
    Fields!VariableValue.Value = 1, "Pass",
    Fields!VariableValue.Value = 2, "Fail",
    Fields!VariableValue.Value = 3, "Abort",
    Fields!VariableValue.Value = 4, "ByPass",
    Fields!VariableValue.Value = "#Error", "NA"
    true, Fields!VariableValue.Value
)
```

Looking at your example, I'm not 100% sure the original or the new expression will even work (is `VariableValue` a number or text?) but hopefully this is better way for you.